# Writing On Image HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
<a href="#">
  <img class="img img-responsive" src="'black-box.png"/>
</a>
```

I have this piece of code, and I was curious how I would be able to write text on top of the image? I don't need to modify the image file itself, just need to display text on top of it.

Comment: you'd use a relative positioned element to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

P {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img alt="this is an alt" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300">
  <p> this is text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make the text to be more per line before it overflows to the next line? At the moment, not much text can fit per line

Comment: @FlyingCitrus101 you can set a `max-width` on p and then it will wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parent div which is relative position and your text div's position needs to be absolute.

```
<div class="container">

<a href="#">
  <img class="img img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300"/>
</a>

<div class="text">
    test
</div>

</div>

.container {
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
}
.text {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}
```

working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sdvwu95g/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#"><span id="img-text"> your text </span>
      <img class="img img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300"/>
    </a>
    
    #img-text {
    
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left:50%;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
}
.img{
position: relative;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>This is my text</span>
<a href="#">
  <img class="img img-responsive" src="your image"/>
</a>
</div>
```